# Is Ubuntu Desktop compatible with Acer Aspire hardware

Tags: compatibility

Does anyone know if Ubuntu Desktop 13.10 is compatible with the Acer Aspire ATC-605-UB11.  This system has the following specs:

Intel processor = i5-4440

Memory = 8GB RAM

Hard Drive Capacity = 1TB

This system also has a specific graphics card.

Appreciate anyone who can answer this A.S.A.P.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Run the Ubuntu live DVD and see for yourself. It will save you time in the long run. The Acer Aspire ATC-605-UB11's specs are more than adequate for Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

I turned secure boot off in the bios and installed mint 16 from a DVD.  Both Windows and Linux seem to be happy.  I could not get the install DVD to boot with secure boot enabled.
I don't know what the ramifications of running Windows 8.1 without secure boot enabled are but it is working.